# How can I mask sub-directory to work as DocumentRoot for multiple domains pointing to the same location?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting, masking

I am trying to mask sub directories to effectively work as DocumentRoot for multiple domains. e.g. I have two domains - `domain1.com` & `domain2.com` both pointing to the same location.

I want `domain1.com` to load contents in the DocumentRoot of the location whereas `domain2.com` should behave as if the DocumentRoot for it is within a subdirectory let's say `domain2.dir`.

How do I achieve this using *.htaccess*? I tried the following but it did not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /domain2.dir [L]
```

The error I get is as below:

```
[Tue Jun 04 17:42:54 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.30] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I would appreciate any help on this.